# Problem when animating a div to the right then adding a new div dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a container div, and an array.
First i prepend 3 divs to the container div.
Then after 3 seconds, i remove the 3rd div, then use jquery animate to transition the 2 remaining divs to the right side, and then i added a new div.

Problem the newly added div was not added to the spot where i want it to be and now theres a huge space between the newly added div, and the remaining 2 div. Also, the vertical scroll bard appears,

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    addBoxes();

    setInterval(function() { removeBox(); }, 3000)
});

var boxArray = [
    {name: "Box 1",},
    {name: "Box 2",},
    {name: "Box 3",},
    {name: "Box 4",},
    {name: "Box 5",},
    {name: "Box 6",},
    {name: "Box 7",},
    {name: "Box 8",},
    {name: "Box 9",},
    {name: "Box 10",},
    {name: "Box 11",},
]

function addBoxes()
{
    for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        $(".container").prepend("<div class='box animated fadeInLeft faster'>"+ boxArray[i].name +"</div>");
    }

    boxArray.splice(0, 3);
}

function removeBox()
{
    if (boxArray.length === 0)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        var card = $(".container .box:nth-child(3)");
        card.addClass("animated fadeOutRight faster").one(function()
        {
            card.unbind().remove();
        })

        //addSingleBox();
        animateRemainingBox();

        setTimeout(function()
        {
            addSingleBox();
        }, 400)
    }
}

function addSingleBox()
{
    $(".container").prepend("<div class='box'>"+ boxArray[0].name +"</div>");
    boxArray.shift();
}

function animateRemainingBox()
{
    $(".box").animate({left: $(".box").width()})
}
```

```css
.container {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.box {
    height: 80%;
    width: 32%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    background: rgb(239, 242, 244);
    box-shadow: 4px 8px 16px #808080;
    display: inline-block;

    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
    margin-left: 1.7%;
    margin-right: 1.7%;
}

.box:nth-child(1) {
    margin: 0px;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using a static element which is hidden after the 3rd div, anything basically, and assing it an ID, again, what ever you choose. use Javascript function to add the next div dynamically with .insertBefore(). The argument passed into the function is the id of that static element.

```
YOUR_Container = document.querySelector('#yourContainerId')
staticNode = document.querySelector('#yourHiddenElementId');
YOUR_Container.insertBefore(newNode, staticNode);
```

this is what's called bulletproofing with javascript, because it won't work for whatever reason and you have no way knowing why

Comment: Iw wont work, because im adding the element using prepend

Comment: did you try it? it's easy to assume the worse. just try different methods. eventually you will hit the spot